# how to sign the byte array with SHA256withRSA having custom private key in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, cryptography

I have a byte array and want to sign it with an Asymmetric private key in Swift code. I have java code below and want same thing in iOS swift.

```
           try {

                final java.security.Signature instance = provider == null ?
                        java.security.Signature.getInstance(algorithm.getJvmName()) :
                        java.security.Signature.getInstance(algorithm.getJvmName(), provider);
                if (signature.getParameterSpec() != null) {
                    instance.setParameter(signature.getParameterSpec());
                }
                instance.initSign(key);
                instance.update(signingStringBytes);
                return instance.sign();

            } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

                throw new UnsupportedAlgorithmException(algorithm.getJvmName());

            } catch (final Exception e) {

                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
```

Tried the below code in Swift

```
public func sign(value: String, base64EncodingOptions:Data.Base64EncodingOptions = []) -> String?    {
    do {
        let keyData = Data(base64Encoded: privateKey)!
        let key = SecKeyCreateWithData(keyData as CFData,
                                       [kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                                       kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,] as NSDictionary, nil)!

        var data = value.data(using: .utf8)!
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        guard let signedData = SecKeyCreateSignature(key,                                                       .rsaSignatureDigestPSSSHA256,                                                         data as CFData,                                                         &error) as Data?
        else {
            return nil
        }
        let signData = signedData as Data
        let signedString = signData.base64EncodedString(options: [])            

        return signedString
    }
    catch {
        //handle error
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: OK.  What parts of the iOS SDK have you looked at and what have you tried?  A quick search at Developer.apple.com reveals an SDK called "Apple CryptoKit".  Perhaps that will give you a good place to start looking.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: And where does that code fail?  What happens when you run it.  I note, at least, that the documentation for `SecKeyCreateWithData` notes that the `kSecAttrKeySizeInBits` attribute is required.

Comment: @ScottThompson CryptoKit does not support RSA, if that is the key they're using. For Sandeep: a good idea is to catch the error that is put in the variable when creating the key and see if you can use that. The security framework, unfortunately, is still a bit old, so it has no do/try/catch

Answer (score -1):

I am using this method to sign a session key:

```
func signature(sessionKeyBase64: String, privateKey: String) throws -> String? {
    let sk = try extractSessionKey(encryptedSessionKeyBase64: sessionKeyBase64)
    let privateKeyDer = try SwKeyConvert.PrivateKey.pemToPKCS1DER(privateKey)
    let signature = try? CC.RSA.sign(sk, derKey: privateKeyDer, padding: .pkcs15, digest: .sha256, saltLen: 0);
    return signature?.base64EncodedString()
}

func extractSessionKey(encryptedSessionKeyBase64: String, privateKey: String) throws -> Data {
    let privateKeyDer = try SwKeyConvert.PrivateKey.pemToPKCS1DER(privateKey)
    let encryptedData = Data(base64Encoded: encryptedSessionKeyBase64)!
    return try CC.RSA.decrypt(encryptedData, derKey: privateKeyDer, tag: Data(), padding: .pkcs1, digest: .sha1).0
}
```

and a below method to check a signature:

```
func isVerified(encryptedKeyBase64: String, signatureBase64: String, signerPublicKeyBase64: String) throws -> Bool {
    let sk = try extractSessionKey(encryptedSessionKeyBase64: encryptedKeyBase64)
    let pk = try SwKeyConvert.PublicKey.pemToPKCS1DER(signerPublicKeyBase64)
    let signatureBytes = Data(base64Encoded: signatureBase64)
    return (try? CC.RSA.verify( sk, derKey: pk, padding: .pkcs15, digest: .sha256, saltLen: 0, signedData: signatureBytes!))!
}
```

with the help of the third party library [SwCrypt](https://github.com/soyersoyer/SwCrypt)